# Best way to set up my program's code

Tags: php, ajax, design-patterns

I'm in the process of creating a new program. It's being created in a way I've never created anything before. The program basically consists of the following:

- **Index.html**          - The interface, just HTML code
- **ActionController.js** - Included by index.html, it contains jquery hooks to interface elements, makes Ajax calls and updates the interface
- **ExampleAction.php**   - One of the many 'Action' files that the ActionController calls to using Ajax. It does numerous things depending on the file, but the layout of the files is the same.

The problems I am having with this setup is as follows:

1.I wasn't able to accomplish creating a singleton for my database class because using ajax I am forced to create a new database instance in every ExampleAction file. Is this normal behaviour or should it be possible and it's probably something in my code? If it should be possible and it's something in my code I will post it later.

If I'm not being clear enough, this is what I tried:
- I renamed index.html to index.php (ofcourse).
- Included my database singleton at the top of this file.
- Made the ajax call to ExampleAction.php.
- ExampleAction.php doesn't have access to the database class and I have to include it again and create a new instance.

2.When I make the Ajax call I send Parameters through a POST. The general layout of the ExampleAction is as follows:

```
$actionInstance = new ExampleAction();
class ExampleAction {
 public __construct() {
  this.GetAction();
 }

 private GetAction() {
  $action = $_POST['action'];
  switch ($action) {
   case "Login":
    this.Login();
    break;
  }

  //Login function, etc. here

 }
}
```

Ofcourse my real code contains sanitization and such, the switch statements are longer and it contains a lot more functions

What I don't like about this is two things. I don't like that I have to instantiate the object every time I make a call to the file, but I guess that can't be helped.

The second thing is that, if I have a lot of functions, my switch becomes huge.

All of these problems are making me think I'm going about this all wrong.

**TL;DR:**
I'm looking for the best way to set up a program such as the one I am making. I get the feeling I'm making my code slower (because of the increasing amount of ajax calls) and harder to maintain by the minute (because of the ever-increasing switch statement.

Comment: **Don't use singletons**. They are evil. Learn about MVC, separation of concerns. You'll have a long road ahead of you, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have to instantiate a new object for every AJAX call is because the AJAX call is a new request to your server from the client. The called script is not running within your program and any set up has to be done at the point the script is called by AJAX.

The best way around this is to use a framework that utilizes MVC such as [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). In short using an MVC framework if used correctly will cut out the need for you to instantiate objects for every AJAX call as this is handled by controllers and you will be able to lose your switch statements as each AJAX call can be to a unique URI with a single controller that handles all these different calls.

**EDIT: in repsonse to comment**
Unfortunately I don't have any experience with Zend Framework but I'm sure the premise is pretty much the same as in Codeigniter. So in Codeigniter you would have an AJAX Controller which extends the main controller and therefore has access to the database and everything else that is setup within the main controller.

Within the AJAX Controller you'll have different methods which handle all the different AJAX calls something like this.

```
//CI_Controller is codeigniter's base Controller
class AjaxController extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        // Can make calls to anything a normal controller can do
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        // You have access to the database because you are extending 
        // and calling the parent constructor
        // $this->db->query();
    }

    public function doSomethingElse() {
        ...
    }
```

To call these AJAX functions your URI's will be http://mysite.com/Ajax/doSomethig or http://mysite.com/Ajax/doSomethingElse

As I pointed out before an AJAX call is a brand new request to your server from the client. When a user requests a page, your PHP code is run on the server and the output sent to the client. Any javascript is run in the users browser. If your javascript makes an AJAX call this is a new request to your server and happens after your PHP from the original request has finished.

Comment: Having worked with Zend Framework I'm having a hard time converting my current setup to use it. Mainly because in my thought process I would still be using Ajax and I would end up having to instantiate the database object again. I'm not saying you're not right, I'm saying I don't know how to work out your suggestion in a way that would solve my problem. I'll mark one of the answers as actual answer later since this seems to be the consensus. I just want to hear a couple of more opinions on the matter.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Hopefully it'll clear things up a bit

Comment: I see, that clears up a lot! I'm not sure where I'll go from here because last time I tried to read Zend Framework's documentation my head exploded (I still got pretty far though). I just couldn't learn anything from it because it just seemed like steps were missing and it was incomplete.. Anyway, thank you, maybe I'll take a look at CodeIgniter to finish this!

Comment: Zend Framework is very good but it's a steep learning curve. Codeigniter is less feature rich than Zend Framework but a lot easier to learn and the documentation is very good.

Comment: Just a small update in case anyone cares, I thought about this answer and I can now see how I'm going to make this work. Thank you again, my code makes me less sick now. The jQuery hooks and code feel like they don't belong in the MVC structure as currently implemented though, but at least the way I handle different cases looks a million times better now.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather hard to simply provide you with the "best way" for your program.

I do however suggest you dive into the MVC pattern and learn about it's structure. After which you can try to implement a similar method in your own code.

Here is a basic explanation about MVC, but do take the time to google and read more then just this bit of text:

> **Define MVC in layman’s terms**
>
> Remember you’re technically minded and
> close to the code. MVC to you is as clear as day, but saying to the
> business ‘Model, View, Contoller’ could give them the impression that
> you are suffering from some form tourette syndrome. MVC won’t mean
> much to the business even after you define them in relation to the
> code. To get the business to understand why this is the answer and
> least of all what it is, can be more of a task than expected in my
> experience. Even some fellow developers have difficulty understanding
> this on occasion.
>
> To get the listener to understand what MVC is and why it works what I
> have tried in the pass is to apply MVC to a different industries where
> the listeners have had more involvement. An example that has worked
> for me in the past in a comparison to the property or even the
> vehicles. Most people have had dealing’s with builders, carpenters,
> plumbers, electricians or have watched the flood of property shows on
> the TV. This experience is a good platform to use and to explain why
> separation such as MVC works. I know you’re probably thinking that
> won’t work as it’s not the same as in software, but remember you’re
> not trying to train the business to become developers or have an in
> depth understanding of MVC, simply explaining to them that separation
> in production is required and that’s what an MVC structure offers.
>
> To give an example of how you could describe this I have very briefly
> explained how separation works in property. Keep in mind this is
> focused on using the system not developing which could be a completely
> different angle of explanation.
>
> **View**
>
> The view in MVC is the presentation layer. This is what the end user
> of a product will see and interact with. A system can have multiple
> views of all different types ranging from command line output to
> rendered HTML. The view doesn’t consist of business logic in most
> clear designs. The interface is fit for purpose and is the area of
> interaction. Therefore you could simply output HTML for consumers to
> interact with or output SOAP/XML for businesses to interact with. Both
> use the same business logic behind the system otherwise known as the
> models and controllers.
>
> In the world of property you could think of the view as the interior
> of a property or the outer layer of a property that the inhabitants
> interact with. The interior can be customised for purpose and the same
> property can have many different types of tenants. For example a
> property of a particular design could contain residential dwellings.
> The same internal space could easily be used as office space, where
> although in the same property has a different purpose. However the
> property structure is the same. Therefore the environment in which the
> users interact does not interfere with the structure of the building.
>
> **Controllers**
>
> The controller is where the magic happens and defines the business
> application logic. This could be where the user has sent a response
> from the view, then this response is used to process the internal
> workings of the request and processes the response back to the user.
> Taking a typical response where a user has requested to buy a book.
> The controller has the user id, payment details, shipping address and
> item choice. These elements are then processed through the business
> logic to complete a purchase. The data is passed through the system
> into the model layer and eventually after the entire request satisfies
> the business definitions, the order is constructed and the user
> receives their item.
>
> If we compare this to a property, we could compare the ordering of a
> book online to turning on a light switch. A tenant will flick the
> switch to on just like ordering a book. The switch itself is an
> element in the view layer which sends the request to the controller
> just like clicking a checkout button on a web site. The business logic
> in this case is what the electrician installed and are embedded within
> the property designs. The switch is flicked, which completes the
> circuit. Electricity runs through all the wires including the fuse box
> straight through to the light bulb. Just like the user receiving a
> book, in this case the tenant receives light. The whole process behind
> the scenes involving the electricity cabling is not visible to the the
> tenant. They simply interact with the switch within the space and from
> there the controller handles the request.
>
> **Models**
>
> The models in MVC are the bottom most layer and handle the core logic
> of the system. In most cases this could be seen as the layer that
> interacts with the data source. In systems using MVC, the controller
> will pass information to the model in order to store and retrieve
> data. Following on from the example above controller definition, this
> is where the order details are stored. Additional data such as stock
> levels, physical location of product of the book amongst many things
> are all stored here. If that was the last book in stock ordered, the
> next request for this item may check if it’s available and disallow
> the order as the item is no longer available.
>
> Sticking with out example of turning on a light switch, this level in
> our structure could be the electricity supply. When the tenant flicks
> the switch, the internal circuit must request electricity to power the
> request which is similar when the user requested data from the
> database, as in data is needed to process a request. If the dwelling
> isn’t connected to an electric supply, it cannot complete the process.
> Business benefits from using MVC
>
> After you get the message across explaining what MVC is, you will then
> have to see what benefits can be obtained from it. I’m not going to go
> into a huge amount of detail here are I’m sure you can apply benefits
> more accurately which are directly related to you actual situation. To
> list just some of the common benefits of an MVC based system here are
> a few examples:
>
> Different skill levels can work on different system levels. For
> example designers can work on the interface (View) with very little
> development knowledge and developers can work on the business logic
> (Controller) with very little concern for the design level. Then they
> simply integrate together on completion. As a result of the above
> separation projects can be managed easier and quicker. The designer
> can start the interfaces before the developer and vice versa. This
> development process can be parallel as opposed to being sequential
> therefore reducing development time. Easy to have multiple view types
> using the same business logic. Clear route through the system. You
> clearly know where there different levels of the system are. With a
> clear route of the system, logic can be shared and improved. This has
> added security benefits as you clearly know the permitted route from
> the data to the user and can have clear security checks along the
> route. Each layer is responsible for itself. (Relates to point 1) This
> means that you can have clean file structure which can be maintained
> and managed much easier and quicker than a tightly couple system where
> you may have lots of duplicate logic. Having a clear structure means
> development will be more transparent which should result in reduced
> development time, maintenance problems and release cycles if applied
> properly.

A specific PHP example about how to implement MVC in php can be found here: http://phpmaster.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/

Additionally: understand that a controller will at some point present you with a "View", this view can be html, xml, json or whatever. So Controllers wil also deal with your AJAX requests.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read up on my problem. I am however using MVC but didn't think it to be relevant because even when using this design pattern I would have the same problem because of the Ajax calls. In the files I called to using Ajax I have no access to any previously instantiated objects, such as the database class. This means I have to reinstantiate the objects I need after every Ajax request which seems like overkill to me.

Comment: If you setup your controller structure you would have. Controllers can inherit/extend eachother, setting up an environment in the process.. And previously instantiated objects could be serialized in Session (probably want to use __sleep and __wakeup) if needed, but thats a bit beyond the scope of your question.