# CodeIgniter - Replace redunant JSON conversion

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, oop, design-patterns

I recently started using Codeigniter after having a structural problem in one of my Ajax-heavy applications. (You can read up on it if you want in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437102/best-way-to-set-up-my-programs-code))

I have a fairly short question. Currently I am making a lot of Ajax requests to different controllers. I open the controllers like this:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct(); 

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
}
```

And at the end of every function I do the following:

```
$this->returnValue['result'] = "ReturnedInfo";
$this->returnValue = json_encode($this->returnValue);
$this->output->set_output($this->returnValue);
```

The code is pretty clear in itself, but I don't want to keep repeating myself. The codeigniter manual says to do the following:

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

But I would still be repeating myself. Also, I don't want to add a function to every controller that does this, even if it does decrease redundancy.

Since all of my controllers return JSON, is there a way to set this globally in a config file maybe, or in any other way?

**TL;DR** I have this same piece of code in every controller/function. Since the output type is always the same, just not the result, is there a way to automate this process across every controller/function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `Ajax_Controller` that extends `MY_Controller` that extends `CI_Controller`.
The Ajax Controller will then inherit from both Controllers.

```
class Ajax_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();

      if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) return show_error('Invalid Request');
   }

   public function jsonOutput($json)
   {
      //some data checking here....

      return $this->output
           ->set_content_type('application/json')
           ->set_header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
           ->set_output($json);
   }
}
```

-

```
class User extends Ajax_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function userMethod()
    {
        $json = json_encode(array(
            '' => ''
        ));
        $this->jsonOutput($json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Totally forgot all about inheritance, haha.

Comment: No worries, it may also help you look at your other code differently.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your controllers from your own base class rather than CI_Controller and put your repeatedly-used function(s) and constructor code in there. Something like:

```
class BaseController extends CI_Controller {
  protected function index() {
    $this->returnValue['result'] = "ReturnedInfo";
    $this->returnValue = json_encode($this->returnValue);
    $this->output->set_output($this->returnValue);
  }
}

class Specific extends BaseController {
  public function index() {
    //do controller-specific stuff

    parent::index();
  }
}
```

I abstract this further if I have groups of controllers with shared code; for example, if I had a bunch of controllers that require the user to be logged-in I create AuthenticatedController, which extends BaseController and add session checks etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. This answer is good too but Philip's example was a little more clear to me and he was slightly quicker.